# Как назначить или прочитать cookies с другого моего сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, cookie

Имеется:

- Сайт №1, который принимает get-параметр "g" с записанным в него значением (напр. ?g=1). Дальше он работает с ним.
- Сайт №2, который должен передать/перезаписать get-параметр "g" с его значением сайту №1.
- Значение get-параметра "g" - публичное и не несет особой ценности, кроме как владельцу сайта. Поэтому его секретность - не важна.
- Оба сайта расположены на разных доменах, принадлежат одному владельцу и могут находится на одном сервере.
- Пользователь, который заходит на сайт №2 с определенным get-параметром, а потом заходит на сайт №1 уже без него.

**Цель:** Нужно, чтобы при заходе на сайт №1, в cookies сайта №1 уже были данные get-параметра, с которым пользователь зашел на сайт №2.

На сайте №1 я разместил js-скрипт, достающий из url get-параметр и устанавливающий его в cookie. Подключил этот скрипт на сайт №2. Но при входе на сайт №2, куки устанавливаются для домена №2. А мне нужно, чтобы они были установлены на домене №1.

Как сделать так, чтобы куки установились для домена №1?
Как я понимаю, мне нужно как-то их передать/назначить сайту №1 в момент загрузки скрипта, но я не понимаю, как это сделать.

Иначе говоря, какой код нужно прописать, чтобы взять get-параметр с сайта №2 и записать его в куки сайта №1?

Answer (score 1):

Можно на сайте нумер 1 написать простенькое API, принимающее GET c вашим параметром и создающее куку. Естессно с ключами, шифрованием и всем таким заумным. Ну и при совершении определённого действия на сайте нумер 2 запрашивать нумер 1 по этому API. Всё очень тривиально.

Comment: Ну так и я примерно об этом, упомянул curl

Comment: @KAGG Design Я не прочитал ваш ответ сразу. + от меня

Comment: Для новичка звучит ужасающе и усложняюще. В одном из мест, мне порекомендовали подгрузить файл (картинку или js) с первого сайта на второй и назначить кукисы первому. Но подробностей не сообщили. Что скажете об этом способе?

Comment: скажу, что велосипед уже изобрели - надо сесть и поехать. А по сему ответ KAGG Design в пункте №1 подходит вам лучше всего. Если оба сайта на WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie и local strorage невозможно использовать на разных доменах. Ну, разве что применять какие-то невнятные ухищрения через общий скрытый iframe с третьим доменом.

Если оба сайта на WordPress, есть два простых пути:

1. Объединить их в multisite и хранить в базе (а она общая) метку пользователя вместо cookie
2. Получив запрос пользователя на втором сайте, сделать в коде php запрос curl ко второму сайту и спросить права пользователя (или еще что-то)

Comment: К сожалению, задача стоит именно с куками. В одном из мест, мне порекомендовали подгрузить файл (картинку или js) с первого сайта на второй и назначить кукисы первому. Но подробностей не сообщили. Что скажете об этом способе?

Comment: Я считаю задачу с куки невыполнимой. Т.н. "способ" противоречит политике безопасности куки и выглядит болтовней. Какое отношение имеет наличие того или иного файла к куки?

Answer (score 0):

Из соображений безопасности нельзя читать/писать куки из другого домена (вопрос о поддоменах одного домена и свойстве domain оставляю на самостоятельное изучение).
Но, как и в любом правиле здесь есть исключение. Cross-domain cookies можно сделать если оба домена твои. Под "твои" я подразумеваю что ты сам можешь на них разместить нужные тебе скрипты. Организовать это можно следующим образом. Пишем скрипт, который читает имя куки из реквеста и выдает значение в респонс, еще скрипт, который ставит куку. Теперь на другом домене мы спокойно можем расположить html где при помощи элементов script можем дергать скрипты с другого домена, которые будут читать/писать куки. Html будет лежать в одном домене, а куки дергать мы будем для другого домена.

Вот простейший пример:

setcookie.php:

```
<?php
    setcookie($_REQUEST["name"], $_REQUEST["value"], time() + 36000);
?>
```

getcookie.php

```
<?php
    $cookiename = $_REQUEST["name"];
    echo "alert('" . $cookiename . " = " . $_COOKIE[$cookiename] . "');";
?>
```

listcookies.php:

```
<?php
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $value) {
        echo "alert('" . $name . " = " . $value . "');";
    }
?>
```

testcookies.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function listCookies() {
    exec(document.getElementById('scriptsLocation').value + 'listcookies.php?rnd=' + 
        Math.random());
}
function setCookie() {
    exec(document.getElementById('scriptsLocation').value + 'setcookie.php?name=' + 
        document.getElementById('cookieName').value + '&value=' + 
        document.getElementById('cookieValue').value + '&rnd=' + Math.random());
}
function getCookie() {
    exec(document.getElementById('scriptsLocation').value + 'getcookie.php?name=' + 
        document.getElementById('cookieName').value + '&rnd=' + Math.random());
}
function exec(sUrl) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = sUrl;
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.defer = true;
    void(head.appendChild(script));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
scripts location on other domain: <input type="text" id="scriptsLocation" value="http://your.other.domain/scripts/location/" /><br />
cookie name: <input type="text" id="cookieName" /><br />
cookie value: <input type="text" id="cookieValue" /><br />
<input type="button" value="Set cookie" onclick="setCookie()" />
<input type="button" value="Get cookie" onclick="getCookie()" />
<input type="button" value="List cookies" onclick="listCookies()" />
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. Проверять работоспособность конкретного примера в Firefox. IE не хочет динамически грузить скрипты у которых в урле есть параметры. Но если это даже и ограничение IE, то это легко обходится через mod_rewrite.

Источник: http://rsdn.org/forum/web/1903262.1